# boto EC2 find all Ubuntu images?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, ec2-ami

How do I find all Ubuntu images available in my region?

Attempt:

```
from boto.ec2 import connect_to_region


conn = connect_to_region(**dict(region_name=region, **aws_keys))
if not filters:  # Not as default arguments, as they should be immutable
    filters = {
        'architecture': 'x86_64',
        'name': 'ubuntu/images/ebs-*'
    }
print conn.get_all_images(owners=['amazon'], filters=filters)
```

I've also tried setting `ubuntu/images/ebs-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-20140927`, `ubuntu*`, `*ubuntu` and `*ubuntu*`.

Comment: aws api filters do not accept globs that I'm aware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS API does not accept globs in search filters as far as I am aware. You can use the owner id to find it. 'Amazon' is not the owner of the ubuntu images Canonical is.

Change `owners=['amazon']` to `owners=['099720109477']`.

There is no owner alias for canonical as far as I can see, so you will have to use the owner id instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. And it does support globs, just tried: `'name': 'ubuntu*ssd*14.04*20140724'` which returned `[u'ubuntu/images/ebs-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-20140724', u'ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-20140724']`